# How to hide axes in matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I put the image in a [NumPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) array, and draw it with the following code. How can I tell the program not to draw the axes, like `(0, 100, 200...)`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(output_ndarray)
plt.savefig(output_png)
```

[image: aflw picture]

Comment: Blatant plug:  If you want to write a numpy array directly to a PNG file, you can use the package [`numpngw`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpngw) that I wrote.

Comment: This is not hiding axes, but ticks and their labels.The `Axes` object also contains the image and other "artists". For those searching for actually hiding the axes: `ax.set_visible(False)`

Comment: What is "aflw" (in the pictire embedded description)? AFLW, [AFL Women's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AFL_Women%27s), Australia's national semi-professional Australian rules football league for female players?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
```

http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html

Answer (score 15):

[image]You can also use...

```
plt.axis('off')
```

[image]

Comment: This is the easiest way to to it. Note for object-oriented api, it is the same `ax.axis('off')` which is nice.